# How to pass a custom component as a 'prop' to another custom component in React.js render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've written two Reactjs components, one is the form (MainForm) where I will place multiple button components (NextButton). When I define the NextButton on the MainForm, I want to specify which component to mount next in the NextButton's handleClick event.

**Here is the NextButton component:**

```
class NextButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(event){
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(parentElement);
        ReactDOM.render(
            this.props.next,
            parentElement
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} value={this.props.value}/>
        );
    }
}
```

**Here is the MainForm component:**

```
class MainForm extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="formWrapper">
                <NextButton value="Custom Code" next= {<NextForm />} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

In the MainForm component, I am attempting to make a NextButton and pass it the component I want to show when the button is clicked, which is handled by the NextButton handleClick function.

I am unable to figure out whether I have a syntax error, or am I just using the wrong approach to accomplish this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something very similar to what you've tried to do, you just need to return valid JSX

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/q3pxnlo9p6

Comment: I just came back to look at this and noticed your response. I actually prefer your recommendation because using the state change allows for flexibility. Thank you, and I apologize for missing it back in January!

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass it in this way. You have to pass it in as a child component.

```
<NextButton value="Custom Code">
   <NextForm />
</NextButton>
```

You can access NextForm inside NextButton with `this.props.children`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, that solved it!